# PowerShell passing DateTime variable to Set-Date

Tags: powershell, datetime

Here is code:

```
$computerList = "localhost", "luna"
$user = Get-Credential powershell
$date = Get-Date
foreach ($computer in $computerList) {
    if ($computer -eq "localhost") { $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer }
    else { $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer -Credential $user }
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        Set-Date -Date $date
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Date' because it is null.
```

Working in console line by line it works but when running script variable $date is null like error says. 
Why is variable $date null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't work either way, you are referring to local variable when executing command in a remote session, you should be calling the variable like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Date -Date $using:date
}
```

[More on remote variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables).